# SAML Signing Certificate - CA Signed vs Self Signed

Tags: certificate, single-sign-on, saml, x509certificate, saml-2.0

I am SSO implementation engineer but lately found it challenging to convince the InfoSec team on using Self Signed Certificate vs. CA Signed Certificate for signing the SAML Assertion.

As CA signing authorities are no longer giving out certificates more than 1 year validity it has become a gigantic task to co-ordinate, guide and update the SAML Certificates on the SP side of the things every year.

I know there is no need for a CA cert to sign the SAML Assertion but I have to convince using Self Signed cert with 3 year validity or something.

1. Are there any CAs that can give us 3 year CA Signed Certificate for SAML?
2. If not 1, what can be a solid way to make the InfoSec understand that there is no need for CA signed certs but a Self-signed Cert is fine with no security issues. Looking for some suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's their reasoning for requiring the signing cert be CA-signed? What benefit do they believe it provides?

Comment: One of the reasoning they would have is well a CA signed is trust worthy than a self signed cert. I need to make them understand that it doesn't really matter as this is not a SSL cert and all it does is signing the SAML assertion with a private key. I need some strong pointers where they can think from my perspective and security perspective (no risk) apart from the time and resources every year we put in to renew.

Answer (score 2):

Many SAML2 providers use their own self-signed certificate to sign assertions (Microsoft Azure for instance).  Service Provider's depend on the trustworthiness of the certificate to decide whether to trust that the assertion is valid.

It is really important that the SP can verify the authenticity of the certificate and that only the IdP certificate can sign the assertion (i.e. there is no possibility that someone else could provide a "valid" assertion).

With a Trusted Root signed certificate the SP trusts your certificate because they trust the Root.  With a self signed certificate the SP trusts your certificate because they trust your certificate.  The distinction is important.

If a SP trusts your certificate because they trust the root, they may trust a bad guys certificate if it was signed by the trusted root.  In general TLS connections there is a one to many relationship that the trusted root works around.  I cannot personally validate the certificate for every web site I go to, so the trusted root does that for me.

In the case of the SP to IdP relationship it is possible to validate the IdP's certificate.  It is possible to fully trust that certificate.  The SP's admin downloads the  certificate and adds it to the SP's configuration.  The SP should be configured to trust only that certificate (the self signed certificate essentially becomes the CA but the IdP may have their own CA).

While it might seem counter intuitive to trust a self-signed certificate more than a trusted root signed certificate, the one to one relationship of the SP to the IdP means that you **can** validate that certificate by obtaining it directly from the IdP configuration page.

That being said, there is a reason why Trusted roots only sign short lived certificates.  The longer the same certificate is used the more likely it could become compromised (someone else may get the private key).